# Handling log (0) in image processing algorithms

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that makes use of the median absolute deviation metric:

[image]

This of course causes problems for 0 intensity values for log(0) is -infinity. The result of the log needs to be used in calculations again and thus -inf - inf = NaN is another issue here. Is there an appropriate way to deal with this without affecting the result much? The image has a lot of 0's so whatever I do is amplified and may mess up the medians.

My current assumption is to set the value to some large negative number but I'm not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: One possibility is to add a small bias to all your pixels. Then 0s will be, e.g., 1e-6, and the calculations do not get bad values.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that is one way of doing it. I'm not sure if these edge cases are having an effect on the overall median. I'm starting to wonder if the exponential should be taken since it is working with the gradient of the logarithmic image.